# How to get sample route arcgis in android?

Tags: android, arcgis

I want to get route between two locations,for that i have found esri sample service i.e :http://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World.
But if i use this service i am getting error as Unauthorized access to a secure. 
I am unable to use this service,Please tell me if any free service for getting route on arcgis map
Thanks.

my code:

```
public void getRouteFromSource(Geometry current_location,Geometry destination_point,boolean isCurrentLocation){
        routeLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        mMapView.addLayer(routeLayer);

        // Initialize the RouteTask
        try {

        String routeTaskURL = "http://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World";
            mRouteTask = RouteTask.createOnlineRouteTask(routeTaskURL, null);

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();                       
        }

    // Add the hidden segments layer (for highlighting route segments)
    hiddenSegmentsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    mMapView.addLayer(hiddenSegmentsLayer);     

    QueryDirections(current_location, destination_point,isCurrentLocation);
}
private void QueryDirections(final Geometry sourceGeometry, final Geometry destinationGeometry,boolean isCurrentLocation) {

    // Show that the route is calculating

    if(isCurrentLocation==false){
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, PollingStationLocatorContant.plase_wait,
            "Calculating route...", true);
    }

//  Log.e("mLocation", "mLocation  "+sourceGeometry);
//  Log.e("POINTTT", "POINTTT"+p);
    // Spawn the request off in a new thread to keep UI responsive
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        private RouteResult mResults;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Start building up routing parameters

                /*Point startPoint = new Point(78.4867, 17.3850);
                Point stopPoint = new Point(79.5941, 17.9689);*/

        //      Log.e("mLocation.getX()",""+ p.getX()+"---"+ p.getY());
        //      Log.e("mLocation.getY()",""+ mLocation.getX() +"----"+ mLocation.getY());

                //Point startPoint = new Point(mLocation.getX(), mLocation.getY());
                //Point stopPoint = new Point(p.getX(), p.getY());

                StopGraphic point1 = new StopGraphic(sourceGeometry);
                StopGraphic point2 = new StopGraphic(destinationGeometry);                  

                Log.e("point1", ""+point1);
                Log.e("point2", ""+point2);
                NAFeaturesAsFeature rfaf = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();
                // Convert point to EGS (decimal degrees)
                // Create the stop points (start at our location, go
                // to pressed location)
                rfaf.setFeatures(new Graphic[] { point1, point2 });
                rfaf.setCompressedRequest(true);

        //  RouteParameters r = new RouteParameters();

                RouteParameters rp = mRouteTask.retrieveDefaultRouteTaskParameters();                   

                //rp.setImpedanceAttributeName("Length");
                rp.setReturnDirections(false);
                // Assign the first cost attribute as the impedance

                rp.setStops(rfaf);
                // Set the routing service output SR to our map
                // service's SR
                rp.setOutSpatialReference(mMapView.getSpatialReference());
                //rp.setImpedanceAttributeName("");

                // Solve the route and use the results to update UI
                // when received
                mResults = mRouteTask.solve(rp);                    

                List<Route> routes = mResults.getRoutes();
                Route mRoute = routes.get(0);

                Geometry routeGeom = mRoute.getRouteGraphic().getGeometry();
                Graphic symbolGraphic = new Graphic(routeGeom, new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.BLUE,5));
                //SimpleMarkerSymbol sls = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED, 10,STYLE.CIRCLE);
                PictureMarkerSymbol pls=new PictureMarkerSymbol(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animation_image));
                mMapView.setExtent(routeGeom, 20);
                Graphic destinatonGraphic = new Graphic(sourceGeometry, pls);
                mGraphicsLayer.addGraphic(symbolGraphic);
                mDestinationGraphicLayer.addGraphic(destinatonGraphic);
                mMapView.addLayer(mGraphicsLayer);
                mMapView.addLayer(mDestinationGraphicLayer);

            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mDestinationGraphicLayer.removeAll();
                noRouteFound=true;


                 e.printStackTrace();
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

            }
        }
    };
    // Start the operation
    t.start();
}

void updateUI() {

    if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()){
    dialog.dismiss();
    if(noRouteFound){

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unable to find route.Please select with in State", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding geocoding services (which may be called for free if data is not stored) routing services do require a token.

As stated in the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Route_service_with_synchronous_execution/02r300000036000000/):

> **Required parameters**: **token**
>   Use this parameter to specify a token that provides the identity of a
>   user that has the permissions to access the service. Accessing
>   services provided by Esri provides more information on how such an
>   access token can be obtained.

What you can do is to go [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/sign-up/) and register a free developer account. You will receive a free token and its related amount of free credits that you can use to query the routing API.

However, the documentation linked above shows samples of response for all possible situations (error, route ok, route not found).

Answer (score 0):

After creating a free developer account follow these steps.

Inside your getRouteFromSource function replace the existing code with this.

```
TOKEN = "The token you receive after you sign up";
CLIENT_ID = "The client_id you receive after you sign up";

try {
        UserCredentials authenticate= new UserCredentials();
        authenticate.setUserAccount("your username", "your password");
        authenticate.setUserToken(TOKEN, CLIENT_ID);
        mRouteTask = RouteTask
                .createOnlineRouteTask(
                        "http://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World",
                        authenticate);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This should solve your problem.